# How to add - in-between strings

Tags: php, php-7

How do I add - in between strings.
Let’s say for instance, I want to add - in 123456789101 at the fourth position three times thereby making it look like this : 1234-5678-9101.

Substr_replace() or str_replace has not solved the problem.

Comment: Are the strings all 12 digits long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this.

Use substr

```
$output = sprintf('%s-%s-%s', substr($string, 0,4), substr($string,4,4), substr(8,4));
```

Use preg_replace

```
$output = preg_replace('/(.{4,4})(.{4,4})(.{4,4})/', '$1-$2-$3', $string);
```

Comment: `.{4,4}`? Why not just `.{4}`?

Answer (score 4):

I would use combination of [str_split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) and [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

```
$code = 123456789101;
$formatted = implode('-', str_split($code, 4) );
echo $formatted; //1234-5678-9101
```